# When does a mailbox processor stop running?

Tags: f#

I am having trouble understanding when a `MailboxProcessor` "finishes" in F#.

I have collected some examples where the behavior is (perhaps) counter-intuitive.

This mailbox processor prints nothing and halts the program:

```ml
let m = MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox -> async {
  while true do
    let! m = inbox.Receive()
    printfn "%i" m
})
```

This mailbox processor counts up to `2207` then the program exits:

```ml
MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox -> async {
  let mutable i = 0;
  while true do
    printfn "%i" i
    i <- i + 1
})
|> ignore
```

This mailbox processor prints `1` then the program exits:

```ml
let m = MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox -> async {
  while true do
    let! m = inbox.Receive()
    printfn "%i" m
    do! Async.FromContinuations ignore // Should wait forever
})

m.Post(1)
m.Post(2)
m.Post(3)
```

Can you explain why `MailboxProcessor` behaves the way that it does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When started, `MailboxProcessor` will run the asynchronous computation specified as the body. It will continue running until the body finishes (either by reaching the end or by throwing an exception) or until the program itself is terminated (as the mailbox processor runs in the background).

To comment on your examples:

- *This mailbox processor prints nothing and halts the program* - I assume you run this in a console app that terminates after the mailbox processor is created. There is nothing blocking the program and so it ends (killing the mailbox processor in the background).
- *This mailbox processor counts up to 2207 then the program exits* - I suspect this is for the same reason - your program creates the mailbox processor, which manages to run for a while, but then the program itself is terminated and the mailbox processor killed.
- *This mailbox processor prints 1 then the program exits* - The body of the mailbox processor hangs and the next two messages are queued. The queue is never processed (because the body has hanged) and then your program terminates.

You will get more useful insights if you add something like `Console.ReadLine()` to the end of your program, because this will prevent the program from terminating and killing the mailbox processor.

For example, the following will process all 100000 items:

```
let mbox = MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox -> async {
  while true do 
    let! msg = inbox.Receive()
    printfn "%d" msg
})
for i in 0 .. 100000 do mbox.Post(i)
System.Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Thank you. The "runs in the background" bit made it clear to me.